# Body background with different colors

Tags: css

I have a problem with an image that I set as `background-image` for the `body` element, but it's not working properly because of the different page lengths. Is there a way to add a different body background-color for each main HTML element?

For example, on this [website](http://nelsonandco.pro/learncenter/) I need the body color around the header to be white, then the main container of the website to have a grey gradient and finally the footer to have a grey solid color.

**Later edit**: Based on the recommendation of Joseph Silber, I've read the [Full Browser width Bars](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) article and in the comments I found a very easy solution for my problem which you can see in the code below or on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPfW2/):

```
#header {
background: white;
margin: 0 -2000px;
padding: 0 2000px;
}
#main   {
background: green;
margin: 0 -2000px;
padding: 0 2000px;
}
#footer {
background: gray;
margin: 0 -2000px;
padding: 0 2000px;
}
.content {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**even later update:** if you have the horizontal scroll problem apply the `overflow-x` property to the html element as well:

```
html, body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What do you consider to be a "main HTML element"?

Comment: Check this out: [Full Browser Width Bars](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/).

Comment: @Diodeus - It doesn't really matter, I was thinking about the `header`, `body` and `footer` when I said 'main HTML elements' but anything that I can tie to a div is ok.

@JosephSilber - thanks, I'll look into that right now.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by creating a reusable `.content` div with a fixed width that I place inside each section, like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Assign the background colors you want for each section to the parent divs, which will "naturally" stretch across the width of the browser window:

```
#header {background: #000;}
#main   {background: #ccc;}
#footer {background: #fff;}
```

Then give `.content` a fixed width:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```